# How should one interpret srinathji art?

Tags: krishna, idols, art

Knowing that SriNathji represents the eight year old krishna, it's unusual that some depictions of SriNathji are unpleasant, eg some are mean looking, some scary, etc.

[*Its values are derived from and its universal-love-themed devotional practices center around the legendary amorous plays of youthful Krishna*](https://vedanta.redzambala.com/traditions/pustimarga-sampradaya-pushtimarg.html)

what are the possible reasons for this discrepancy? Artistic merit, or is it fate (naseeb), karma, etc?

Humans are creatures of habit (bhava).

Also, the features might affect the worshiper's psychology:

> Look at the deity with eyes and take darshan, then close your eyes
> and visualize His presence filling you and everything around you.

<s>Perhaps the artist had other things in mind, like trying to combine the original impression with a cosmic vision of the god. Or maybe they project their personal feelings about god into the image itself.
Another reason might be that mundane worship of SriNathji via iconography is considered morose - ***“It (Pushtimarg) is spontaneous, selfless and motiveless love for Krishna.”***</s>

EDIT:  consider the eye(s) of srinathji. looks like a **crescent moon**.  i'm not saying this is what prabhu vallabhacharya had in mind.

Comment: the posthumous depiction of Srinathji is an expression of Nathdwara style of painting coming out of the Rajasthan state of India

Comment: Stop trolling by nonstop delete/undelete.